# local python files cannot be imported in setup.py

Tags: pip, python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a Python project with a `setup.py` script in the root directory. I want to run a function from the `inclider.py` module before excecuting `setuptools.setup()`.

```
│   inclider.py
│   pyproject.toml
│   setup.py
│
└───justatest
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───apps
            app1.py
            app2.py
            __init__.py
```

To do this, I added `import inclider` at the top. However, I saw a strange behavior:

When I run `pip install .`, *pip* complains that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inclider'`. But, it works fine when I run `python setup.py install` instead.

Interestingly, when I comment `import inclider`, and execute `inclider.write()` in `setup.py` using `subprocess.run`, it works fine!
but I want to know why this weird behavior happens.

The `setup.py` file looks like below:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import inclider

setup_args = dict(
   packages        = find_packages(where="."),       
   package_dir     = {"": "."},                        
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

Comment: I recommend you provide a [mre], leave out everything not related to the issue (extension, cython, numpy, etc.)

Comment: Is `inclider.py` supposed to be installed? Or is it only supposed to be available during installation (but not installed)?

Comment: @sinoroc No, it only has to be avaiable to setup.py

Comment: @sinoroc I also provided a minimal example without extensions.

Comment: Maybe it is because `inclider.py` needs to be added to `MANIFEST.in` so that it is included in the source distribution (but not in the wheel and not installed).

Comment: @sinoroc I included `inclider.py` in `MANIFEST.in` , but I am getting the same error.

Comment: This should work. Maybe also add the content of the minimal `pyproject.toml` as well as the output of both commands `pip install .` and `python setup.py install`.

Comment: OK, I am confused. I managed to reproduce the issue. I did not spend much time so I might have missed something. But indeed it fails, and I am quite convinced that it used to work. I wonder if it never actually worked or if something changed (in pip?).